# Странное поведение команд в Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian

Непонятно почему в Debian Linux команды стали работать странно. Запускаю `php -i linux` — переходит на новую строчку и не выводит никакой информации.
`composer update` — то же самое, переход на новую строчку и всё.

Answer (score 1):

проблема была в php
после переустановки все заработало